# Solving a PDE with perturbed boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I want to solve a PDE where I know the solutions for one boundary condition and need the solution for a slightly perturbed boundary.

As an example, suppose I know the solution to Laplace's equation
 $\nabla ^2 V = 0$ where $V=0$ on $f(x,y,z)=0$ and want to find the solution for $V=0$ on $f(x,y,z)+g(x,y,z)=0$ where $g\ll f$. I can't find a reference for how to find a perturbative solution to this.

(My particular problem is that I want to find the potential $V$ where $V=0$ on the surface $r=1+\delta \sin{\phi}$ in the usual spherical polar coordinates and $\delta\ll 1$.)

Comment: Would it help to have a more specific example of the former case? That is what I was really interested in. Suppose we take the well trodden case where $V=0$ on a unit sphere and zero at infinity as our 'known' solution. Then how do I go about the perturbed problem where $V=0$ on $r=1+\delta \sin{\phi}$ where $\delta<<1$ and $\phi$ is my polar angle in spherical coords?

Comment: I think that you can just expand the boundary condition around the unperturbed boundary $r=1$ as $0=V(1)+\delta\sin(\phi)V'(1)$, and use an expansion $V=V_0+\delta V_1+\ldots$.